# TeamCity can't find TagBuilder ASP.NET 3.0.0.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild, teamcity

The (ms)build log for **team city** throws the following error multiple times:

> error CS1070: The type name 'TagBuilder' could not be found. This type
>   has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Consider adding a
>   reference to that assembly.

It's a local Asp.net MVC project running MVC3.0.0.1 from the nuget package installed with

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.MVC –version 3.0.50813.1

This also Installed System.Web.WebPages 1.0.0.0 (nuget package)

My weg config contains:

```
   <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.1" newVersion="3.0.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

The System.Web.WebPages & Mvc dlls are set to copy local in the references

I'm getting clueless how to solve this error, It works on my machine, since it's all nuget & copy local I would expect it not to have GAC related issues, (there's no asp.net mvc installed on the build server anyway)

Comment: I fixed this problem by manually upgrading to WebPages 2.0, but I don't get why 2.0 isn't the default for the mvc 3.0.0.1 dependency ...